DMS endpont Test endpoint connection Error
when i connect DMS source endpoint  manually with servername, username and password .
I am able to connect to postgres DB
But when i try to connect with AWS Secrets Manager, Test Connection shows some error.
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to build connection string Unable to find Secrets Manager secret, Application-Detailed-Message: Failed to retrieve secret. Unable to find AWS Secrets Manager secret Arn 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:......' The secrets_manager get secret value failed: curlCode: 28, Timeout was reached Too many retries: curlCode: 28, Timeout was reached

role provided is
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dms:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

What am i doing wrong. Is there any issue in role or any other issue we see.

https://repost.aws/questions/QU3bEbNsc9RzCpLw8qKYC-IQ/dms-test-endpoint-failed
follow this document and in the comments you will get the answer.

I created a VPC endpoint for secretsmanager on the same subnet.  I have DNS enabled on the VPC and the VPC endpoint, which I thought would suffice, but it did not.  I recreated the instance with secretsManagerEndpointOverride per the dms documentation, still failing with timeout.

